# State value not change when dispatch to another reduces in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, redux-toolkit, useselector

I am building login system. I am having problem with store state value when I use Selector function. in my system, I want to get isSuccess, error, userInfo from store state values

`/login/index.js`

```
const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin);
console.log(userLogin);
const { isSuccess, error, userInfo } = userLogin;
```

if error it will show error message on UI, otherwise if isSuccess it will show success message. isSuccess appears when post to api success (it mean user login success) and user data is dispatched to loginSuccess reduces else error value dispatched to loginFail reduces

`/action/userAction.js`

```
import {
loginSuccess,
loginFail,
} from "\~/redux/user/userLoginSlice";

export const login = (inputs) =\> async (dispatch) =\> {
try {
const {data} = await request.post("/auth/login", inputs);
dispatch(loginSuccess(data));
localStorage.setItem("userInfo", JSON.stringify(data));
} catch (error) {
console.log(error.response.data)
dispatch(loginFail(error.response.data))
}
```

. however instead of just getting isSuccess in loginSucces reduce, it also get error when previous login was loginFail
[console.log(userLogin)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5FtH.png). it should only show userInfo and isSuccess. anyone help me to solve this problem with . this is reduces

`userLoginSlice.js`

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';


const userLoginSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'userInfo',
    initialState: {},
    reducers: {
        loginSuccess: (state, action) => {
            state.isSuccess = true;
            state.userInfo = action.payload;
        },
        loginFail: (state, action) => {
            state.error = action.payload
        },
    },
});

export const { loginSuccess, loginFail } = userLoginSlice.actions;

export default userLoginSlice.reducer;
```

and my reduce store

`store.js`

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

import productModalReducer from './product-modal/productModalSlice';
import cartItemsSlice from './cart/cartSlide';
import userLoginSlice from './user/userLoginSlice.js';
import userRegisterSlice from './user/userRegisterSlice.js';
import userUpdateSlice from './user/userUpdateSlice.js';

const userInfoFromStorage = localStorage.getItem('userInfo') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userInfo')) : null;

const initialState = {
    userLogin: { userInfo: userInfoFromStorage },
};

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        productModal: productModalReducer,
        cartItems: cartItemsSlice,
        userLogin: userLoginSlice,
        userRegister: userRegisterSlice,
        userUpdate: userUpdateSlice,
    },
    preloadedState: initialState,
});
```

State value not change when  dispatch to another reduces in redux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this could be because `loginSuccess` is only adding `userInfo` and `isSuccess` to the state but not omitting previous `error`.

Perhaps try reset state value to exclude `error` in the reducer:

```
const userLoginSlice = createSlice({
  name: "userInfo",
  initialState: {},
  reducers: {
    loginSuccess: (state, action) => {
      //  Reset state to omit error message in loginSuccess
      state = { isSuccess: true, userInfo: action.payload };
    },
    loginFail: (state, action) => {
      //  Could add "isSuccess: false, userInfo: null" if needed
      state = { error: action.payload };
    },
  },
});
```

Or return a state value instead of using Immer proxy state:

```
const userLoginSlice = createSlice({
  name: "userInfo",
  initialState: {},
  reducers: {
    loginSuccess: (state, action) => {
      //  Reset state to omit error message in loginSuccess
      return { isSuccess: true, userInfo: action.payload };
    },
    loginFail: (state, action) => {
      //  Could add "isSuccess: false, userInfo: null" if needed
      return { error: action.payload };
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: I don't know why but this way is not return any state value :(( , payload have value but  state is not.